# Chang color or position of a subelement of an obj

Tags: javascript, aframe

i am looking for how to change the color or the position of a subelement of an big obj file.
At the moment, i am loading a huge obj, with over 100 sub-elements unsing

`<a-entity obj-model="obj: #band-obj; mtl: #band-mtl" position="-5, -5, -5" rotation="0, 0, 0" scale="5, 5, 5"></a-entity>`
(obj and mtl already defined).

Has anyone successfully animated parts of a huge model and is able to give me a hint on how to get the sub-elemtsa using js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the mesh with `yourEntity.getObject3D('mesh')`. From there you have access to the sub-tree and can use methods such as `getObjectByName` or `getObjectByProperty` or `traverse`.

The mesh is also returned in the event detail of `model-loaded` or `object3dset` event.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('model-modifier', {
  init: function () {
    this.el.addEventListener('object3dset', evt => {
      if (evt.detail.type !== 'mesh') { return; }
      this.modifyMesh(this.el.getObject3D('mesh'));
    });
  },

  modifyMesh: function (mesh) {
    // Modify here.
  }
});

// ...

<a-entity obj-model model-modifier>
```